# How do I unzip a tar gz archive to a specific destination?

Tags: linux, tar, gzip

I want to unpack a `.tar.gz` file to a specific directory.

The archive file is in `/root/Documents`. I want to unzip it into `/root/Desktop/folder`. The folder structure in zipped file should be preserved in the destination directory.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

You have two choices:

```
cd /root/Desktop/folder
tar xf /root/Documents/file.tar.gz
```

or

```
tar xf file.tar.gz -C /root/Desktop/folder
```

Comment: thanks, how about `gzip -dc archive.tar.gz | tar -xf - -C /destination` ?

Comment: what `-C` stands for?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka From `man tar` -C, --directory DIR change to directory DIR

Comment: `tar -xvjf foo.tar.bz2` for those who are looking for *bz2* like me

Comment: You actually don't have to specify the compression format anymore with modern tar.  I edited the answer so it will work with bz2, xz, and whatever else you want to throw at it.

Comment: Both of these seem to require manually creating a directory first though :/ (Not that it's hard, it's just an annoying extra command I don't wanna have to do). oh well

Comment: @Zoe `tar -xf foobar-1.2.tgz -C /opt --one-top-level=foobar` https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/478341/5164