# Can one extract the files in a .tar.gz and upload them individually onto cPanel?

Tags: tar, wordpress, gzip, cpanel, unzip

I am in the process of migrating my website from Bluehost to a different hosting company. I downloaded the entire backup of the cPanel (61 GIG) successfully, but uploading files is incredibly much slower than when downloading files. This is probably because my company barely does any uploading, so all the transfer speed(?) was allocated to download by the ISP.

I'm not a networker, so I'm unsure of the technicalities.

Is there a way to extract the files in the .tar.gz backup, and then upload them individually onto the new cPanel so as to transfer quicker?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/348205/152004

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH on both servers, it might be worth syncing the data using rsync. You can start Rsync in the background, so it won't be necessary to keep the terminal/console open.

In case you're interested, you can check the following article on how to use rsync between 2 servers. It has some good examples:

https://www.atlantic.net/vps-hosting/how-to-use-rsync-copy-sync-files-servers/

And how to start rsync in the background:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141710/running-rsync-in-background/38671530

Creating a backup then downloading it and then uploading again, might take a huge amount of time.

Hope that help!

Answer (score 0):

If you log in to cPanel you should be able to create files and upload them using the File Manager. In here you can create and upload folders as you see fit.

To unzip a `.tar.gz` file you need an archive manager that works with this file type such as WinRAR.

I recommend installing a fresh version of WordPress to your server and start uploading your theme files to:

```
/wp-content/themes/
```

Followed by the files in your uploads folder located under:

```
/wp-content/uploads/
```

You should find the uploads directory will have the largest files. Getting the rest working first will give you a good place to start since you should have a mostly working site before taking the time to upload the larger files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).